# C# panel flickering when scroll value changed

Tags: c#, scrollbar

how can i reduce flickering?

C# panel flickering when scroll value changed

that's a windows form based project

[Translate is a user control contain two textbox and blue backgroudcolor.]

my implementation:

```
    ScrollBar sb = new VScrollBar();
    translate[] t = new translate[5];

    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //
        sb.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
        sb.Scroll += sb_Scroll;
        panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value = 0;
        sb.Top = panel1.Top;
        sb.Height = panel1.Height;
        this.Controls.Add(sb);
        //


        Point p = new Point(10, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            t[i] = new translate();
            t[i].Left = p.X;
            t[i].Top = p.Y;
            panel1.Controls.Add(t[i]);

            //p.X += 100;
            p.Y += 110;
        }
    }

    void sb_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        //panel1.Invalidate();
        panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = sb.Value;
    }
```

Comment: If on WinForms, try setting the Form's `DoubleBuffered` to `true`.

Comment: yorye nathan - tried but doesn't work..!

Comment: @warrior Use `@` to address people in comments. That way, they get notified and can see it in their inbox. What is the `translate` made of? Does it include heavy graphics?

Comment: @YoryeNathan - no , that's only contain two textbox and two label http://iren.freeiz.com/up/d519c02f134f.jpg

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of tactics for this in WinForms, and firstly you might consider enabling double-buffering of the window and/or controls by settings the [`Control.DoubleBuffered`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered.aspx) property to true.

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether this control should redraw its surface using a secondary buffer to reduce or prevent flicker.

So, this should *reduce* flickering, but not necessarily eliminate it. That depends.

Answer (score 0):

Try using flicker free custom panel control.

- Add new class "NonFlickerPanel" to your C# application.
- Replace autogenerated class code with C# code shown below.
- Use NonFlickerPanel object instead of Panel object in your application.

  ```
  public partial class NonFlickerPanel : Panel
  {
     public NonFlickerPanel() : base()
     {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint,
                            ControlStyles.UserPaint 
                            ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, 
                            true);
     }
  }
  ```